# add and commit file in git repository don`t work

Tags: git

I have a python-file namd "fileA.py" in my Dropbox and want to add + commit these file in a new git repository (PROJECT) in my dropbox. (P.S. I worked with git bash)

Here is my code:

$ mkdir PROJECT

$ cd PROJECT

$ git init C:/Users/Name/Dropbox/

Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Name/Dropbox/.git/

Now, I continue with:

$ touch fileA.py

$ git add fileA.py

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I have no idea what`s going wrong. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Hum... Is your command line situated in the folder where the .Git is located when you launch the Git add?

Comment: Sorry, whats the `commend line`? Did you mean the git bash?

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing your "Dropbox" directory as a git repo, rather than your "PROJECT" directory.  Try these steps:

```
$ mkdir PROJECT
$ cd PROJECT
$ git init
$ touch fileA.py
$ git add fileA.py
```

And see if that works.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But how can I get the new repository with the file in my Dropbox?

Comment: You should be able to move the PROJECT directory there and have Dropbox track it. Git repos are self-contained (the `.git` directory which contains git info is inside the project directory). Or, if you're starting from scratch, just create your PROJECT directory under the Dropbox directory to begin with.